# Why are carriage returns being ignored?

Tags: c#, itext

I recently upgraded the iTextSharp DLL in one of my apps from 4.0 to 5.5.13 (a steep jump, I know).  In doing so, I've found that now in some documents that contain objects that are doing nothing but inserting carriage returns, that they are being ignored.  My content before and after is now smushed together.  What behavior changed during these versions that caused this behavior?  Is there a simple fix?

Comment: Make sure you project got fully compiled after installing new version of ITextSharp.  Often the compiler dependencies will not recognize a library change.

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm that was done.  This is definitely a behavior change in the product.  I'm running the same code on 2 different servers to test;  one with the old DLL, and one with the new, and getting these differing results.

Comment: See BUG at bottom of following : https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/releases/release-itext-5512 on change log tab.

Comment: Hmmmm...that could be the source of the issue.  I'll see if I can upgrade to yet another newer version, to see if the issue persists.  I'm worried that I'm jumping quite a few versions, that perhaps I missed a change in core functionality somewhere that is making my objects like work like they used to...

Comment: Okay, so I at least found where things go awry.  Version 5.3.3 was the last one to work correctly for me.  All other 5.X versions thereafter are whacking lines from my content.

Comment: Notes say following in 5.3.5 : Important: to avoid confusion about which XML Worker version corresponds with which iText version, we're jumping from XML Worker 1.2.1 to XML Worker 5.3.5. From now on the versions of XML Worker and iText will be kept in sync.  So maybe the IText version is wrong.